# How to search FTS3 table so that searched word show top of the list

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, fts3

I have a FTS3 table in Android SQLite database. Database is working fine. Now I want to search in table that has word column. Searching is also fine but the problem is when I search with a word the searched word is in the bottom or another position in the list. Suppose I want to search "GOOD" here I want the only "GOOD" will be in top of the list other will be bottom of the list.

Please see my code.

```
cursor = db.query("wordfts", new String[]{"id,word,mean"}, "wordfts" + " MATCH ?", new String[]{"*"+constraint.toUpperCase() + "*"}, null, null, "word", "5");
```

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

The 7th argument of the `query()` method is the `ORDER BY` clause of your statement.
So with your code the results are simply sorted by the column `word`.
But if you want at the top the row(s) that match exactly your pattern, you must change it to:

```
upper(word) = 'GOOD' desc
```

So change your code to this:

```
cursor = db.query(
    "wordfts", 
    new String[] {"id,word,mean"}, 
    "wordfts MATCH ?", 
    new String[] {"*" + constraint.toUpperCase() + "*"}, 
    null, 
    null, 
    "upper(word) = '" + constraint.toUpperCase() + "' desc", 
    "5"
);
```

Or better use `rawQuery()` so you can use `?` placeholders to pass all parameters, including the one in the `ORDER BY` clause, making your code safer:

```
cursor = db.query(
    "SELECT id, word, mean FROM wordfts WHERE wordfts MATCH ? ORDER BY UPPER(word) = ? DESC LIMIT 5",
    new String[] {"*" + constraint.toUpperCase() + "*", constraint.toUpperCase()}
);
```